# Handle time change (summer- and default time) in MongoDB with C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, utc, isodate

I have a centralized logging service written in C#. This service receives log entries (in JSON string) and add them in a MongoDB collection. I use the official C# MongoDB driver and MongoDB Version 3.0.

Let's say I have a document with this basic structure (and example):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("562c2785a075b738c484ad99"),
    "Service" : "WebServer A",
    "Description" : "User has logged in",
    "SourceTime" : ISODate("2015-10-25T00:41:15.469Z")
}
```

As you can see in this document I have a date field called "SourceTime". This UTC format doesn't tell me whether the document is created in summer- (+02:00) or in default time (+01:00).

I would like to ask you what's the best way to store a date field with an ISODate object without having problems with summer- and default time?

Is it better to store an ISODate with following format in C#?

```
{ 
    "SourcTime" : ISODate("2015-10-25T01:41:15.469+01:00") 
}
```

If yes, does anyone has an example how to achieve that with C#?

At the moment, I add a document as follows:

```
    // parse String _document to a BsonDocument
    BsonDocument document = BsonDocument.Parse(_document);

    // Change SourceTime field to a DateTime object
    var TimeElem = document.GetElement("SourceTime").Value.ToString();
    DateTime newTime = DateTime.Parse(TimeElem);

    // Update document
    document.Set("SourceTime", newTime.ToUniversalTime()); // result ISODate("2015-10-25T00:41:15.469Z")

    // Add to MongoDB
    var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(_collectionName);
                    collection.InsertOneAsync(document);
```

Thank you very much for your help. Very appreciate it.

Regards

Comment: Can you please clarify what "problems with summer- and default time" do you have? ISO 8601 does not support named time-zones (like PDT/PST) - so you you really need to know if particular moment in time/space was during summer time or not you need to store that piece of info differently.

Comment: Thanks a lot. When the service stores a document at 12am in local time, MongoDB stores it as UTC time. That means, during daylight the value will be 10am (we have UTC+01:00) and during standard time 11 am. This is fine but if I have to query through the collection, it seems I always have to know the UTC time. Is there a simple way how to query with a local time? Another problem is during a time change. From daylight to standard time, I got some documents twice because the "SourceTime" field went back 1 hour. Therefore, I thought to append "+01:00" or "+02:00" in SourceTime could solve it.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB uses a Bson Date which does not store the timezone within the date -

> The official BSON specification refers to the BSON Date type as the UTC datetime.

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#date

The `ISODate("2015-10-25T01:41:15.469+01:00")` is just a javascript helper method to allow you to convert between an ISODate and a BsonDate so the offset within the string just change converted back to a UTC time.

If you require the timezone or the offset you will need to manually store this within the document, and convert it back after deserialization.